# Port forwarding In Ubuntu 20.04 with minikube

Tags: networking, server, iptables, port-forwarding

I'm trying to use minikube in my server. I've finished setting about kubernetes and I can get access to `192.168.49.2` which I got from `minikube ip` in server ssh (`curl`).

Let's say my server's public ip is `12.34.56.78`. I want to port-forward to minikube when I access to `12.34.56.78`.

I found a way using `iptables`.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 12.34.56.78 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.49.2:80
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.49.2 --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```

Below is the result of `iptables -t nat -L`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             12.34.56.78          tcp dpt:http to:192.168.49.2:80

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.49.0/24      anywhere
```

However it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

+) Before I executed second command, connection to server in browser just put out an error however, after I executed second command, browser loaded infinitely. Also no log was generated in app.

Comment: I just used nginx reverse proxy